# MailChimp API v3 - Get members by email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0, gibbon

I am using MailChimp API v1/v2. In that version, I could get `member-info` for multiple members by providing their emails to [`member-info`](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/member-info.php) API

Now, I want to upgrade to v3, however, I am unable to find the equivalent API endpoint for `member-info` in v3. I can't use `/batches` operation, as I will be calling the API on the fly and will show the response to my users.

Any pointers/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to look up multiple list members with v3 without using the batch API, but you can get each member one by one using this endpoint:

[GET /lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#read-get_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash)

Here's an example using the [Gibbon](https://github.com/amro/gibbon) gem:

```
email_hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("test@example.com") 
request = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key:"YOUR API KEY")
member_info = request.lists("YOUR LIST ID").members(email_hash).retrieve
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this way but this will give me only a single member info, while I needed batch members' info. Anyways, as you said, looks like we don't have `member-info` for multiple members - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is also a /search-members endpoint you could use to find your members.
http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/search-members/#read-get_search_members